# No podspec found for `flutter_user_agentx` in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_user_agentx/ios`, while running application on ios. Android is working

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I am trying to run my flutter application in ios, and while pod installs I am getting an error ([!] No podspec found for `flutter_user_agentx` in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_user_agentx/ios`). I am using a dependency named "flutter_user_agentx", On android is working fine, a Few days back it was working fine for ios also but today I am getting this error.

I want to run my flutter application on ios.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that package is broken in iOS.It's a fork of the original repo. Not the official one.

Use the below package instead.

https://pub.dev/packages/fk_user_agent

[GitHub issue link](https://github.com/j0j00/flutter_user_agent/issues/22)

Answer (score 0):

I got Same problem

flutter_user_agentx is broken on iOS. I use https://pub.dev/packages/fk_user_agen.

Resource:https://github.com/j0j00/flutter_user_agent/issues/22

I Little late But I think it will be usedfull.

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens when you add a new package and there are no pods for ios for that package. However, you will get a lot of pods problem, but mostly following these steps will solve them:

- run `flutter clean`
- Delete the following files in the `ios` folder: `Podfile` and  `Podfile.lock` and the folder `Pods`
- run `flutter pub get`
- go to the 'ios' folder using `cd ios`
- run `pod install --repo-update` (to install the pods again, and if u face any problem try without `--repo-update`)
- Run your app, from command line using 'flutter run' which will take a little bit longer

---

**UPDATE**
You don't need to delete the `podfile` but delete `Podfile.lock` which is enough

Comment: After deleting the Podfile, I am unable to successfully execute pod install as it shows the error message: 'No `Podfile' found in the project directory'.

Comment: You need to do `flutter pub get` first

Comment: Also You don't need to delete the podfile but delete Podfile.lock which is enough